# Made a copy of a class in the same package eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, classpath, buildpath

Project A has project B added to its buildpath and works fine (no runtime exceptions). 
In B, I made a copy of one of the classes, placed it in the same package in B renamed it(to say "myNewClass").
In A, I imported the newly created class (which sits in B),created an instance and called a method of this instance (and everything compiled fine). 
The issue is when I run my code and it hits this line of code it throuws a classNotFoundException.

It might be useful to mention that a small question mark is showing next to "myNewClass" in the package explorer view.

How can "myNewClass" be added to the buildpath to stop the runtimeexception from happening?

Thanks in advance for any replies.

Comment: and `myNewClass` is public ?

Comment: please paste the code of myNewClass...........i think u r not changing the name of class.....

Comment: Did you clean and rebuild both projects?

Comment: The class has the correct name, and both projects has been cleaned and rebuilt.

Answer (score 0):

After adding myNewClass to projectB, create a jar of project B and ad it to build path of project A. This should work fine.

Comment: It did not work. It seems like the issue is Project B not recognizing myNewClass hence the question mark.

Comment: I found out why the question mark was there. The question mark indicates that the resource is not under version control. But would that contribute to this exception being thrown?(don't know)